# How to index with post.jar in solr characters like accented letter

Tags: java, apache, solr, special-characters, entities

We are using solr to make a custom searcch engine, but we have a problem, characters like accents letters give us problem with post.jar.
We solved the "&" problem using &
Is there a way to use entities like èor other?
Can anyone help us?

Comment: Does this help? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Why_don.27t_International_Characters_Work.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar post.jar 'my UTF-8 strings here'
```

Comment: Thank you! was more than a month that I could not solve the problem! WE LOVE YOU!!